# How to copy column names of fields whose values are null of one dataframe and create another

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark-sql-2.4.1v with java 1.8.

I have a data something like below

```
val companyDf = Seq(
  (101,"2018-12-31","700.0","300.0","200.0","400.0","500.0","600.0","900.0","800.0","100.0","1100.0"),
  (102,"2018-12-31","700.0","300.0","200.0","400.0","500.0","600.0","900.0","800.0","100.0",null),
  (103,"2018-12-31",null,"300.0","200.0","400.0","500.0","600.0","900.0","800.0","100.0","1100.0"),
  (104,"2018-12-31",null,"300.0","200.0","400.0","500.0","600.0","900.0","800.0","100.0",null),
).toDF("id","create_date","col_imp_1","col_imp_2","col_imp_3","col_imp_4","col_imp_5","col_imp_6","col_imp_7","col_imp_8","col_imp_9","col_imp_10")
```

I need to check few mandatory columns like "col_imp_*" , if it is null/empty I need to capture those fields info into another dataframe to store in table as below

> Result should be

```
-------------------------------
id   | null_field_col          |
-------------------------------
102   | col_imp_10             |
-------------------------------
103   | col_imp_1              |
-------------------------------
104   | col_imp_1,col_imp_10   |
-------------------------------
```

How can this be achieved?
I guess I can use "when" clause but how to add them into another datafame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
val colsToCheck = companyDf.columns.filter(_.startsWith("col_imp"))

companyDf
  .select($"id",concat_ws(",",colsToCheck.map(c => when(col(c).isNull,lit(c))):_*).as("null_field_col"))
  .show()
```

gives:

```
+---+--------------------+
| id|      null_field_col|
+---+--------------------+
|101|                    |
|102|          col_imp_10|
|103|           col_imp_1|
|104|col_imp_1,col_imp_10|
+---+--------------------+
```

You can omit the first line with `.where($"null_field_col"=!="")`